# $f :\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with closed fibers sending connected to connected

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a map with closed fibers that sends connected sets to connected sets. Is it true that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Choose an $x_0$ and define $g:\mathbb (0,\infty)\to[0,\infty]$ by
$$g(\varepsilon) = \inf\{|x-x_0|: |f(x)-f(x_0)|=\varepsilon\} $$
Because the fibers of $f$ are closed, $g(\varepsilon)$ is always positive and the infimum is actually a minimum.

Furthermore $g$ must be non-decreasing, because if $g(\varepsilon_1)>g(\varepsilon_2)$ for $0<\varepsilon_1<\varepsilon_2$, then the image of $[x_0-g(\varepsilon_2),x_0+g(\varepsilon_2)]$ under $f$ would not be connected.

This should give you enough to satisfy the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity at $x_0$.

Comment: Should the variable of your function $g(\delta)$ perhaps be changed from $\delta$ to $\epsilon$? Otherwise, the $\delta$ in the last sentence is inconsistent with the earlier $\delta$'s, which is confusing.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, you're right. Good catch.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Why the closed ness of the fibres of $f$ imply that $g(\epsilon)$ is always positive ?

Comment: @SaunDev: $g(\varepsilon)$ is the distance from $x_0$ to the union of two fibers. Since this union is closed, if its distance to $x_0$ must be positive; otherwise it would contain $x_0$, but it's easy to see that it doesn't.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Ah ! Thanks , could you also please elaborate the non decreasing nature of $g$ also ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @SaunDev: Either $f(x_0-g(\varepsilon_2))$ or $f(x_0+g(\varepsilon_2))$ will be $f(x_0)\pm \varepsilon_2$ so the image of $f$ of the interval between $x_0\pm g(\varepsilon_2)$ and $x_0$ (which image is by assumption connected) will have to contain $x_0\pm \varepsilon_1$.